# VirtualBoxで仮想マシンの作成ができません

Tags: virtualbox

VirtualBoxとCentOS7vmをダウンロードし、起動

新規作成からVirtualHardDiskの部分で、「すでにある仮想ハードディスクを使用する」というところを選択

「CentOS7vm.vdi」を選択すると左に黄色の三角マークと右に「通常.アクセスできません」と表示されます。

書籍の指示通りに進めているのですが、良く分からなくて行き詰ってます。
原因がわかる方いらっしゃいませんか。

追記です。ダウンロードしたファイルを解凍するよう指示があったのですが、画像にある内の「CentOS7vm.vbox」をクリックすると、virtualboxが起動して下の画面になります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力][image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ダウンロードした CentOS7vm に付いての詳細 (入手元 URL 等) を追記してください。

Comment: URL: https://book.impress.co.jp/books/1119101009
こちらのページにあるダウンロードボタンを押しました。

Comment: VirtualBox のバージョンはいくつでしょうか？ / こちらの環境だと最新版 (v7.0.10) ですが、`*.vbox` をダブルクリック、もしくはツールバーの「追加」で `*.vbox` を指定すれば正常にインポートされます。 / 解凍先のフォルダも OneDrive など特殊な場所を指定していないかを念のため確認してみてください。

Comment: バージョンは7.0.10です。.vboxをダブルクリックすると、virtualboxが起動するのですが、右側に「can’t openmachine」という表示が出ます。解凍先のフォルダはpc内のユーザというフォルダに保存されています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CentOS7vm.zipをファイルとして展開していないのではないでしょうか。
参考
https://sosakubiyori.com/zip/

その後の手順は

> 「CentOS7vm.vbox」をクリックする

でよいと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。クリックすると上に掲載した画像の2枚目の画面になります。その後、何をすればいいのかが分からない状況です。

Comment: 事情が変わり、一旦仮想環境の構築はストップすることになったため、解決済みにしておきます。回答して頂いた方々ありがとうございました。